# How to make a CruiseControl.NET project not-buildable

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

We'd had a CC.NET project building for a few months now and are ready to move on to the next version.  I'd like to leave the project in the CC.NET dashboard, but not allow anyone to do a "Force Build".

Is there a way to config the project to no longer build?  I can remove the project triggers, but am looking for a way to stop all future builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version are you using? In CCNET 1.6, they introduced the [showForceBuildButton](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Project_Configuration_Block) attribute for your `<project>` element.

Comment: That particular project is on an older server, but this is exactly what I was looking for.  I might just move the project to the 1.6 server to get this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 1.5 or newer, you can specify [project level security](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Default_Project_Security) and set the forceBuild property to "Deny"

Comment: This seems like a possible good solution as well, but I don't have users/security on my site, so it won't apply to me.